# bulk update one table using value in another table

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g

If I find a max value in my database of LIM50177

```
lim_id
LIM50172
LIM50173
LIM50174
LIM50175
LIM50176
LIM50177
```

How can I loop through another table and for every base_id go and bulk replace the temp_id with a new lim_id?

```
temp_id base id desc
1008    720 GP
1009    721 GT
1010    722 GA
1021    723 P
1021    724 G
1021    725 X
```

In other words 
The data will be updated as follows:

```
temp_id base id desc
LIM50178    720 GP
LIM50179    721 GT
LIM50180    722 GA
LIM50181    723 P
LIM50182    724 G
LIM50183    725 X
```

Comment: Are you using a sequence for `lim_id`?

Comment: yes it's a alpha/numerical sequence

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence every time you generate the `lim_id` values so you get unique values.

*(Don't use the values in the other table to calculate the maximum value as, if the table is updated in two sessions at the same time and you are always basing the next value off the maximum value in the table then neither session will see the updates performed by the other session and you can end up generating identical "next" values in each session. Instead, every time you generate the "next" value always get that "next" value from the sequence.)*

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE lim_id_seq START WITH 50178;

CREATE TABLE temp_data ( temp_id, base_id, "desc" ) AS
SELECT CAST( 1008 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 720, 'GP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( 1009 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 721, 'GT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( 1010 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 722, 'GA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( 1021 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 723, 'P' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( 1021 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 724, 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( 1021 AS VARCHAR2(10) ), 725, 'X' FROM DUAL
```

**Update using the Sequence**:

```
UPDATE temp_data
SET temp_id = 'LIM' || lim_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

**Result**:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_data;
```

> ```
> TEMP_ID  | BASE_ID | desc
> :------- | ------: | :---
> LIM50178 |     720 | GP  
> LIM50179 |     721 | GT  
> LIM50180 |     722 | GA  
> LIM50181 |     723 | P   
> LIM50182 |     724 | G   
> LIM50183 |     725 | X
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7ee2b95929975fd2ec89fdd0a1a324d)*

Comment: is there a way i can just store a sequence in a variable and not a table and for every base_id just add the next sequence in the variable?

Comment: @Jacques A [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) is not stored in a table.

Comment: just one other question, if i didnt want to use a sequence but rather store the values in a table, how can I loop through each of my base_id and just update the table with a unique temp_id

Comment: I don't recommend that. (As I mentioned it leaves you open to unexpected concurrency issues when you try to generate ids manually without using a sequence). However, if you really want that then edit it into your question and don't accept an answer yet and someone else might be able to provide you a solution.

Comment: If you want to use a table and insert into both that and your temp table from a sequence then [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ad0df55581834893b473d86de6222be5)